# Developing a secure WS client for consuming a Axis2 Web Service with Rampart WS Security module?

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, apache-axis, ws-security, rampart

I have a Axis2 web service secured using Rampart. I do want to develop secure clients for it, preferably JAX-WS based. I tried a lot of tutorials but they are so closed tied with each other, like including Axis2 libraries in the client side. The client should be fairly independent of the WS service framework, as the service can be consumed by .NET based clients or even PHP based clients.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you would want to be able to feed the policy defined for your Rampart secured web service into your JAX-WS client.

That ought to be doable.  As you say-- the idea is to be able to execute different client and server technologies, standardized around WSDLs...

We're only just getting into this - so I don't have any hands on knowledge for you.

But I would think you should be able to copy the policy info for your rampart on the server in the services.xml file and put it in your client.

This seemed pretty helpful:

https://metro.dev.java.net/guide/

Sections 12 and 18 in particular.